# Google Firebase auth/redirect-cancelled-by-user when deployed on Android using Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, firebase-authentication, phonegap

Have gone through the steps listed at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova multiple times now and while it works in the browser platform, when deployed to Android the external browser launches to the google sign-in page correctly but once the details are entered and the next button is pressed it brings you back to the app and fails with the error code of auth/redirect-cancelled-by-user and an error message of "The redirect operation has been cancelled by the user before finalizing".
Phonegap version: 0.4.5
Cordova version: 10.0.0
Cordova Android Platform version: 9.0.0

I tried adding the following code to device-ready as recommended but nothing is produced in the console:
`universalLinks.subscribe(null, function (eventData) {console.log(eventData.url);});`

The browser will close automatically 95% of the time but there is the very rare and occasional chance it does not close automatically and the "continue to app name" button will appear.
I have been looking at the forms for a while now and it seems everyone else that has posted about this issue did so a long while ago back when cordova was around version 6-8.
I have also tried different versions of cordova-universal-links-plugin like cordova-universal-links-plugin-fix and cordova-universal-links-plugin-fixed

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with this issue, I think I may have found the solution. The `config.xml` file that is located in the resources folder in the Android project (file path `platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml`) was not kept up to date with the `config.xml` file in the root of my project thus it had an out of date link for my Firebase project as well as its dynamic link.